# how to write sql query in if condition of ksh shell script

Tags: sql, oracle, shell, unix, ksh

I'm very new to shell scripting and I want to write an SQL query inside IF 'condition', not inside the if 'block'. Can anyone help me with that?

My code:-

```
if [sqlplus -s /@user_pass_dbname << EOF select param_value from my_table where my_id=1 EXIT; /EOF == '7878'];then
echo "works!!"
else
echo "doesn't work"
```

Output:-
syntax error at line 3: `<<' unmatched

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the value from sqlplus in a variable instead:

```
result=`sqlplus -s /@user_pass_dbname <<EOF
set head off feedback off
select param_value from param_table where param_id=1;
exit
EOF`

if [ $result = 965 ]; then
 echo "works"
else
 echo "doesn't work"
fi
```

Comment: It was not coming right, so I echoed $result. It says 
    PARAM_VALUE
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    965
So, it is printing the table itself, not just the value.

Comment: di you add the head off and feedback off?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have environment to test now,But i think you need to put quotes(').

```
    'sqlplus -s /@user_pass_dbname << EOF select param_value from my_table 
    where my_id=1 EXIT; /EOF'
```